# Binding for-loop output with threshold to a vector in R 3.3.1

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I'm doing the Coursera R Programming course and am having trouble trying to set up binding of for-loop results to a vector.

I have already made sure that the analysis code works on a single table, but I am not entirely sure how to get it to bind all `332` values.

```
  corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0, id = 1:332) {
  filename <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  a <- numeric()
  for(i in id) {
    tmp_data <- read.csv(filename[i])
    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(tmp_data))
    if(nobs < threshold) {
      a} else {
      nonas <- tmp_data[!is.na(tmp_data$sulfate) & !is.na(tmp_data$nitrate),]
      x <- corr(nonas$sulfate, nonas$nitrate)
      a[i] <- x
      }
  }
  a
}
```

When I run this, I get a return of this error:

```
> x <- corr("specdata", 20)
Error in list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) : 
invalid 'path' argument
```

In other functions, I have had no problem with the `list.files` line.  I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: "specdata" is in your working directory? Otherwise you need to specify the full path, for example: "C:/Users/Documents/R/specdata"

Comment: Yes, "specdata" is inside my working directory.

Comment: What if you try `x <- corr(directory="specdata", threshold=20)`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I unknowingly had a recursive in my code.  It should have been cor(), NOT corr().

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0, id = 1:332) {
  filename <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
  a <- c()
  for(i in id) {
    tmp_data <- read.csv(filename[i])
    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(tmp_data))
    if(nobs > threshold) {
        nonas <- tmp_data[!is.na(tmp_data$sulfate) & !is.na(tmp_data$nitrate),]
        x <- cor(nonas$sulfate, nonas$nitrate)
        a[i] <- x
      }
  }
  b <- na.omit(a)
}
```